# why do all my contact links move down when i hover over it... i only want one to move

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I want my contact section of my page to have links to my social. I applied `:hover` to my `span` classes to make it move up by 5px. Although ALL of my links move down when i hover over the desired link... what did I do wrong can some one please help.. Code is below.

```css
#contact {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(235, 216, 247) 20%, var(--color-primary) 80%);
  height: 30vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}

.contact-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.contact-section-header {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contact-section-header h2 {
  font-family: var(--text-primary), sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid var(--color-secondary);
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 0 45% 0.7rem;
}

.contact-section-header p {
  font-family: var(--text-primary);
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-links {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 35px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.contact-links i {
  color: rgb(204, 49, 173);
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
}
 
.ig-blanket-link,
.ig-hair-link,
.fb-link-span,
.fcc-link-span {
  font-family: var(--text-primary);
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
} 

.ig-blanket-link:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.ig-hair-link:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.fb-link-span:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

span:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.contact-links a {
  display: flex;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section id="contact" class="contact-section">
      <div class="contact-section-header">
        <h2>Contact Me!</h2>
        <p class="social-p">Links To My Socials Are Below:</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="contact-links">
        <a 
          href="#"
          target="_blank"
          class="contact-details"
        ><span class="ig-blanket-link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>My Blanket Page</span>
        </a>

        <a 
          href="#"
          target="_blank"
          class="contact-details"
        ><span class="ig-hair-link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>My Hair Page</span>
        </a>

        <a 
          href="#"
          target="_blank"
          class="contact-details"
        ><span class="fb-link-span"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>My Facebook Page</span>
        </a>

        <a 
          id="profile-link"
          href="#"
          target="_blank"
          class="contact-details"
        ><span class="fcc-link-span"><i class="fab fa-free-code-camp"></i>freeCodeCamp.org</span>
        </a>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wrote `span:hover` and that includes all of the span elements, and i used `transform: translatey(-5px);` instead of padding

```css
#contact {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(235, 216, 247) 20%, var(--color-primary) 80%);
  height: 30vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}

.contact-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.contact-section-header {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contact-section-header h2 {
  font-family: var(--text-primary), sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid var(--color-secondary);
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 0 45% 0.7rem;
}

.contact-section-header p {
  font-family: var(--text-primary);
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-links {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 35px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.contact-links i {
  color: rgb(204, 49, 173);
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
}
 
.ig-blanket-link,
.ig-hair-link,
.fb-link-span,
.fcc-link-span {
  font-family: var(--text-primary);
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
} 

.ig-blanket-link:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: translatey(-5px);

}

.ig-hair-link:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      transform: translatey(-5px);

}

.fb-link-span:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      transform: translatey(-5px);


}
.fcc-link-span:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      transform: translatey(-5px);
}



.contact-links a {
  display: flex;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section id="contact" class="contact-section">
      <div class="contact-section-header">
        <h2>Contact Me!</h2>
        <p class="social-p">Links To My Socials Are Below:</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="contact-links">
        <a 
          href="#"
          target="_blank"
          class="contact-details"
        ><span class="ig-blanket-link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>My Blanket Page</span>
        </a>

        <a 
          href="#"
          target="_blank"
          class="contact-details"
        ><span class="ig-hair-link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>My Hair Page</span>
        </a>

        <a 
          href="#"
          target="_blank"
          class="contact-details"
        ><span class="fb-link-span"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>My Facebook Page</span>
        </a>

        <a 
          id="profile-link"
          href="#"
          target="_blank"
          class="contact-details"
        ><span class="fcc-link-span"><i class="fab fa-free-code-camp"></i>freeCodeCamp.org</span>
        </a>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the size of the element is increased by the padding-bottom, other elements are also affected.　　
Once you put padding-top: 5px to the state before the change as shown below, it will work.

```
span{
  padding-top: 5px;  
}
span:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  padding-top: 0px;  
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

However, since the range of influence is large, it may be better to narrow down the code a little more.